# Error occurred in switching view in Fragment Navigation Drawer ,said no view found for fragment PlaceholderFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I had created a simple app via Android Studio using Navigation Drawer Fragment.

I was trying to show another view (like `layout_about.xml`) when user clicks an item of `ListView`.

So I use `setContentView()` in `public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` but when I run it, an error occurred :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.akakanch.sample, PID: 28848
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 (com.akakanch.sample:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{250d0b42 #1 id=0x7f0c0050}
```

Here's my the only place I had change:

*MainActivity.java*

```
 @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_about);


    }
```

So, how can I change the view correctly？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you are calling set content view from there.
just set the layout you want to see as the layout of the fragment you are replacing and you will see it

inside the fragment:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_about,container,false);  
      //do your fragment stuff 
      return view;
    }
```

if you do this when you replace the fragment using fragment manager you will see the layout_about layout

Comment: Sorry,what's that (set the layout you want to see as the layout of the fragment you are replacing) means?Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: How about click the ListView?You know,there is a ListView attached to the Navigation Drawer Fragment.How about when user click one of the item in ListView,then app will change current view to another?Can you give me sample code?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void setUpSlideMenu() {
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            //close if the selected item equals current fragment
            if (mCurrentNavItem == item.getItemId()) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.drawer_menu_about:
                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_menu_browser:
                    setFragment(new BrowserFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.drawer_menu_library:
                    setFragment(new LibraryFragment());
                    break;
            }
            //save selected id
            mCurrentNavItem = item.getItemId();
            item.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

setFragment:

```
//pop all and set a new fragment
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        //pop all fragment
        mFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```